# Updateing a Table with a Stored Procedure or Functions in Catel

Tags: entity-framework, catel

I've set up a database with EF6 and Code First and I am using Catel's Repository Pattern to communicate with the database.

Now, I am curious as to how you would call a stored procedure (or even a Scalar Valued Function) on my database using Catel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to call the stored procedure using the `DbContext` itself as you usually would:

```
using (var dbContextManager = DbContextManager<MyEntities>.GetManager())
{
    var dbContext = dbContextManager.DbContext;
    var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ReturnType>("storedProcedureName", params);
}
```

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx*

Comment: So, by creating a service for my stored procedure, i should then be able to access it without actually exposing the dbcontext?

Comment: Very nice answer, I have added this to the docs as well: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+stored+procedures+and+functions

Comment: I ended up creating a service to handle this. just one note on the code, it should read `var dbContext = dbContextManager.Context` and not `dbManager.DbContext`